# Target unusually numbers with nth-child CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I don't tend to use `nth-child` as I've always found it confusing but im wondering if its possible to target certain children?

I have a list and I'd like to target the 1,3,5,8,10,12 elements only, is this possible with nth-child? I have used nth-tester ([link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/#)) but had no luck...

```
<ul>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
</ul>
```

If not is it possible to do this with javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not a series in any perspective..

Comment: You have to use multiple selectors. Is there any other common attribute? What is the reason behind getting these numbers?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zFk67/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple `:nth-child` selectors, but there's no way to combine them.

```
ul li:nth-child(1), ul li:nth-child(3), ul li:nth-child(5), ... {
    /* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most robust way is to use a list of selectors, each of which targets one child:

```
li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(5), 
li:nth-child(8), li:nth-child(10), li:nth-child(12) { 
  /* declarations here */
}
```

It is possible to construct a little shorter alternative, but it looks more obscure. You can target all odd-numbered children with number less 7 and, with a separate selector, all even-numbered from number 8:

```
li:nth-child(2n+1):not(:nth-child(n+7)),
li:nth-child(2n+8) {
  /* declarations here */
}
```

This is, however, more difficult to maintain. For example, the second selector would also match item number 14, so if new items are appended, you would need to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you with both CSS and jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/wildandjam/PzN9L/

```
ul li:nth-child(1){
    background:red;
}


$("ul li:nth-child(10)").addClass("number10");
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
1,3,5,8,10,12  contain only target value.so you have to use **[contains][1]**
```

selector

```
$( "ul li:contains('TARGET')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple `:eq` selector:

```
$('ul').find('li:eq(0), li:eq(2), li:eq(4),li:eq(7),li:eq(9),li:eq(11)');
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that this answer is only for jQuery and not CSS.

Comment: He said he wants to do it with CSS, but then asked "if not, can I do it with JS?"

Comment: But it is possible with CSS...!

Comment: @Barmar: ohh its there in question title... didnt see that :P

Answer (score -2):

You could do a hack in html:

```
<ul>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li style="display:none;">TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>TARGET</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    border: 1px solid #c00;
}
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwjJ8/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: It will be targeted in css but it wont be visible. So in this case the visible targeted elements will be: `1,3,5,8,10,12`. Otherwise it would be: `1,3,5,7,9,11`.

Comment: That's an awful idea. You're hiding the element, so your code works!?